# Apache Flink: How to count the total number of events in a DataStream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have two raw streams and I am joining those streams and then I want to count what is the total number of events that have been joined and how much events have not. I am doing this by using map on `joinedEventDataStream` as shown below

```
joinedEventDataStream.map(new RichMapFunction<JoinedEvent, Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object map(JoinedEvent joinedEvent) throws Exception {

                number_of_joined_events += 1;

                return null;
            }
        });
```

**Question # 1:** Is this the appropriate way to count the number of events in the stream?

**Question # 2:** I have noticed a wired behavior, which some of you might not believe. The issue is that when I run my Flink program in IntelliJ IDE, it shows me correct value for `number_of_joined_events` but `0` in the case when I submit this program as `jar`. So I am getting the initial value of `number_of_joined_events` when I run the program as a `jar` file instead of the actual count. Why is this happening only in case of `jar` file submission and not in IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not working. The behavior you  noticed when executing the program via a JAR file is expected.

I don't know how `number_of_joined_events` is defined, but I assume its a static variable in your program. When you run the program in your IDE, it runs in a single JVM. Hence, all operators have access to the static variable. When you submit a JAR file to a remote process, the program is executed in a different JVM (possibly multiple JVMs) and the static variable in your client process is never updated.

You can use Flink's metrics or a `ReduceFunction` that sums `1`s to count the number of processed records.

Comment: wow, ur genius. it is a static variable, I used an accumulator in joinedDataStrem and it worked in the jar file. it took me my weekend though :). Thanks a ton